# VueJS -- handle dropdown state in dynamically generated list of dropdowns

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to handle the open/close state and value for multiple dropdowns in a dynamically generated list. With a single dropdown, an "isOpen" variable in `data()` works but in a list, all the dropdowns (predictably) open and close with the same click and their selected values are the same. i.e. it's as if they are all the same dropdown.

I'm not sure how to use the key of the outside list to distinguish all the dropdowns from each other and / or to make sure they all have a unique value associated with them. Any help would be awesome.

```
// main list
<div
  class="main-list"
  v-for="(item, index) in list"
  :key="index"
>
  <div class="list-item">
    <h1>Item Title</h1>
    <p>Description</p>

    // dropdown for this item in above v-for
    <div
      @click="isOpen = !isOpen"
      :class="{ 'is-open': isOpen }"
      class="dropdown-wrap"
      :key="index"
    >
      <div class="dropdown-title">
        {{ selectedLocation ? selectedLocation.location_name : "Select Location" }}
      </div>
      <ul class="locations-list">
        <li
          class="location"
          v-for="(item, index) in locations"
          :key="index"
          @click="setLocation(item)"
        >
          <a
            class="location-link"
            :aria-label="item.location_name"
          >
            {{ item.location_name }}
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the reason is the ways you declare making `isOpen` belongs to mainList.vue, but it should belongs to each dropdown and independent across the components.

The best practice is you need to create another Vue component call Dropdown and move all logic to there

**Dropdown.vue**

```
<template>
 <div class="list-item">
    <h1>Item Title</h1>
    <p>Description</p>

    // dropdown for this item in above v-for
    <div
      @click="isOpen = !isOpen"
      :class="{ 'is-open': isOpen }"
      class="dropdown-wrap"
      :key="index"
    >
      <div class="dropdown-title">
        {{ selectedLocation ? selectedLocation.location_name : "Select Location" }}
      </div>
      <ul class="locations-list">
        <li
          class="location"
          v-for="(item, index) in locations"
          :key="index"
          @click="setLocation(item)"
        >
          <a
            class="location-link"
            :aria-label="item.location_name"
          >
            {{ item.location_name }}
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>


  </div>
</template>
```

**Please remember to move all related data/methods from mainList to Dropdown.vue (such as isOpen, selectedLocation, .....)**

Then in **mainlist.vue,** you just need to call it out

```
<div
  class="main-list"
  v-for="(item, index) in list"
  :key="index"
>
 <drop-down />
</div>
```

Now each **Dropdown** should use independent `isOpen` and not depends on each other

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to gave isOpen as unique for all click. that's way you can manage all dropdowns

Like.. isOpen[index] or else you know